# Htaccess Rewrite mode in php not working with this code

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My First URL is :

```
http://localhost/get.php?lang=fa&action=news&news=218
```

I wanted to have This :

```
http://localhost/fa/news/218
```

I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /get.php?lang=$1&action=$2&news=$3 [L]
```

But it's not Working. ( 404 PAGE)

What is the problem ?

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava Index , localhost

Comment: By location I means what is path or directory for this .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava Its on :: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www

Comment: Have you turned on modrewrite in apache? Or is it even apache?

Comment: Are `get.php` and `.htaccess` in same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the following on my local environment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ get.php?lang=$1&action=$2&news=$3
```

The result is: get.php?lang=fa&action=news&news=218